# Can't change checkbox state from jquery ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the state of the checkbox in case the request fails. But it won't change it from inside the `fail` function of jquery's ajax:

```
$('.checkbox').on('change', function () {
    let checked = $(this).is(':checked');

    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        // ajax parameters
    })
    .done(function () {
    })
    .fail(function () {
        $(this).prop('checked', !checked);
    })
});
```

When I use `$(this).prop('checked', !checked);` outside the `fail` and inside the `on('change'..`, it works.

I even tried to log the content of `$(this)` and `checked` in the scope of the `fail` function and it looks like it does get the checkbox element and the value

Comment: You can try using the checkbox's ID and do: $('#checkbox').removeAttr('checked');

Comment: thanks, I edited the post before you commented, changed it to class instead of id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use $("#checkbox") instead of $(this)

"this" cannot work inside "fail" because it refer to ajax function not the changed element

```
$('#checkbox').on('change', function () {
    let checked = $(this).is(':checked');

    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        // ajax parameters
    })
    .done(function () {
    })
    .fail(function () {
        $("#checkbox").prop('checked', !checked);
    })
});
```

you can also set a variable with "this" and reuse it inside "fail":

```
$('.checkbox').on('change', function () {
    let checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    let _this = this;
    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        // ajax parameters
    })
    .done(function () {
    })
    .fail(function () {
        $(_this).prop('checked', !checked);
    })
});
```

Comment: Good answers explain what they change and why it should solve the problem. This reads like a game of spot-the-difference and I don't see a difference.

Comment: @Quentin he used the id instead of `$(this)`. In my case it won't help because I have to use `$(this)`, because I am using class, my mistake for changing the post to id selector instead of class selector. Edited the post

Comment: @Supertommino, sorry, I had a mistake, it's a class not id. What can I do in case of a class? How can I then pass reference to the element to the ajax?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
$('.checkbox').on('change', function () {
    let self = $(this);
    let checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    

    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        // ajax parameters
    })
    .done(function () {
    })
    .fail(function () {
        self.prop('checked', !checked);
    })
});
```

Because in the `.fail()` section context `$(this)` changes, we cant use it to uncheck the checkbox 
So I save the context `$(this)` to the variable `self` before, when context `$(this)` works with checkbox, and after that use it in the `.fail` section

Comment: thank you, you are correct, but I already marked the other answer as he wrote it before you and I didn't see it (but upvoted your comment)